# memory allocation for variables in java

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I have a question about how java deals with unused variables.

Let's say that i have the following code:

```
int notUsedVariable = aMethodThatExecutesSomethingImportantAndReturnsInt(someParameter);
```

Then I never use notUsedVariable in the code.
Will that variable actually be stored, or java is smart enough to ignore the variable when compiling?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot simply ignore the variable as the method may be modifying other parts of the object. It will definitely be compiled into bytecode, then the JIT compiler will optimize the bytecode depending on the runtime behaviour,

Comment: @ExtremeCoders, the way I read the question, @BMF is not asking whether `aMethodThatExecutesSomethingImportantAndReturnsInt` is invoked or not. The question is whether space is made in the thread's stack for the `notUsedVariable` int.

Comment: Don't worry about it. If it's a function-local variable, the run-time storage cost in practice is virtually nothing, as the allocation would at worst consist of subtracting a slightly larger number from the CPU's stack pointer when entering the function. In fact, the JIT could say to itself that it's going to "store" it in the CPU register used for the called method's return value. Then the cost of storage is zero whether it does it or not! The worst cost is too small to benchmark but you could use [PrintAssembly](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly) to examine it.

Comment: Where is `unusedVariable` declared? The answer depends a lot on this. e.g. If it's an instance variable, it can never be compiled away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My observation has been that javac may omit the store operations of unused variables **if**:

1. The variables are marked as `final` **and** are initialized in the declaration;
2. You do **not** compile with local variable debug info (`-g:vars`)

If you compile with `-g:vars`, javac will keep the variables loads and stores in tact for debugging purposes.  It does not appear to consider non-final variables as eligible for removal.

Test for yourself.  My results with JDK 7 are below.  The results were identical with a JDK 8 EAP.

Input:

```
class MyTest {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        int a = 1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String... p0);
  Flags: PUBLIC, STATIC, VARARGS
  Code:
    stack=1, locals=2, arguments=1
         0: iconst_1
         1: istore_1
         2: return
```

Input:

```
class MyTest {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        final int a = 1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String... p0);
  Flags: PUBLIC, STATIC, VARARGS
  Code:
    stack=1, locals=2, arguments=1
         0: return
```

As others have said, in either case I would expect the JIT optimizer to omit any unnecessary store operations.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the `final` variable must be initialized in the declaration.  If you were to write `final int a; a = 1;`, the variable would not be optimized away.

Comment: the main difference is that `a`, in `final int a = 1;`, is a constant variable whereas in `final int a; a = 1;` it is not.

Comment: Well, `a` is constant in either case by the definite assignment analysis rules laid out in the spec.  But javac probably doesn't do full DAA when determining whether it can safely remove a variable.  It probably checks the `HASINIT` flag that the compiler sets during an earlier pass, resulting in a cheaper but stricter optimization.

Comment: Actually it is not a constant in the second example. See the last paragraphs of http://stackoverflow.com/a/13235726/829571. In particular, it needs to be final **and**  initialized with a compile-time constant expression, which is not the case (it is not initialized in the declaration statement).

Comment: D'oh, terminology fail on my part.  Touché.  It is final, and the value is guaranteed to be set exactly once (i.e., "constant"), but it is not recognized as a _constant variable_.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

If `notUsedVariable` is a local variable, the assignment will probably be ignored by the JIT compiler (but we are talking about one register read/write, i.e. sub-nanosecond stuff on modern desktop processors). As demonstrated by MattBall the bytecode will keep the assignment.

If `notUsedVariable` is a member of the class, the result will need to be stored as the field might be accessed later on and it would probably be impossible for the compiler to prove otherwise (a new class could be loaded that does not exist yet for example).

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned *just* about the static compilation step, and not [the JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation), this is simple to check by comparing the bytecode generated from two slightly different classes, using [`javap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html):

```
class WithLocalVar {

    private static int methodWithSideEffect() {
        System.out.println();
        return 42;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = methodWithSideEffect();
    }
}

class WithoutLocalVar {

    private static int methodWithSideEffect() {
        System.out.println();
        return 42;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        methodWithSideEffect();
    }
}

✗  javac With*
✗  javap -c WithLocalVar
Compiled from "WithLocalVar.java"
class WithLocalVar extends java.lang.Object{
WithLocalVar();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   invokestatic    #4; //Method methodWithSideEffect:()I
   3:   istore_1
   4:   return

}

✗  javap -c WithoutLocalVar
Compiled from "WithoutLocalVar.java"
class WithoutLocalVar extends java.lang.Object{
WithoutLocalVar();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   invokestatic    #4; //Method methodWithSideEffect:()I
   3:   pop
   4:   return

}
```

Therefore, **no,** the compiler won't optimize away the `istore_1`. [The JIT is another story...](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/underst_jit.html)

Answer (score 2):

javac does not perform many optimizations. The JIT, on the other hand, does

Check out http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/it-haggar_bytecode/

Here is a qoute.

> More importantly, the javac compiler does not perform simple
>   optimizations like loop unrolling, algebraic simplification, strength
>   reduction, and others. To get these benefits and other simple
>   optimizations, the programmer must perform them on the Java source
>   code and not rely on the javac compiler to perform them.

There is also another thread going into more detail about this.
[Optimization by Java Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981460/optimization-by-java-compiler)

Comment: *"To get these benefits and other simple optimizations, the programmer must perform them on the Java source code and not rely on the javac compiler to perform them."* is quite misleading. The programmer should instead rely on the JIT to perform these optimisations. In other words, don't start unrolling your loops manually!

Answer (score 2):

Let's compile an example

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String... args) {
       int a = 1;
   }
}
```

We get

```
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    Code:
       0: iconst_1       // push integer 1 on stack      
       1: istore_1       // pop integer from stack, store it in local variable 1
       2: return        
}
```

We can see that local variable was not removed. **It was stored**.

**Please remember that at the time of execution optimizations may happen.**

Comment: It's important to point out that this applies only to bytecode compilation, whose details have little effect on the runtime execution of the code on modern JVMs.

Comment: The results also depend on the level of debug info generated by the compiler (i.e., whether `-g:vars` is specified) and whether the variable is marked as `final`.  See my answer for the differences.

Answer (score 0):

It will be stored based upon the scope of the variable that when the scope ends, garbage collection will clean up the memory used by the variable.

I edited once of my Test classes for a class variable and local variable and then used Eclipse to inspect the class file.  (Eclipse complains that the variable is never used.)

```
// Compiled from UserLoadTest.java (version 1.6 : 50.0, super bit)
public class org.dev.user.UserLoadTest extends org.test.BaseTestCase {

  // Field descriptor #6 I
  public int myVariable;
```

...we can see that the class file sees this

```
@org.junit.Test
  public void testBasicUserLoad() throws java.io.IOException, org.custommonkey.xmlunit.exceptions.XpathException;
      0  aload_0 [this]
      1  ldc <String "user_01.xml"> [24]
...
org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLAssert.assertXpathEvaluatesTo(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.w3c.dom.Document) : void [85]
    223  aload_2 [reloaded]
    224  invokevirtual org.testHarness.Result.getDocument() : org.dom4j.dom.DOMDocument [81]
    227  astore_3 [d]
    228  return
```

line 224 is a simple declaration of a variable using

```
    Document d = reloaded.getDocument();
```

This does nothing with `d` but the class file recognizes that the variable was created.

Comment: I read this a bit hastily and see you mentioned the compiler.  During runtime, the variable will be stored until garbage collection. You can look at the byte code of class files and see references stored for variables declared regardless if they are used.